# disable horizontal scroll on mobile web

Tags: css, mobile-website

I'm having an issue where horizontal scrolls appear on certain phones for my site.
I tried to put `overflow-x: hidden` but it's not working.
The width is auto, so that it will actually automatically resize the web to suits the screen size. All other phones are fine except when viewed in blackberry, nokia e52, and Windows mobile, the horizontal scroll will appear.

Any advice?

Comment: It seems like the banner image makes the whole site needs to have horizontal scroll for certain phones. Anyway to make the banner image to auto resize?

Answer (score 155):

Simply add this CSS:

```css
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
  position: relative
}
```

Comment: This one is the only one that worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Yes best answer, put it into your media query to avoid overflow on mobile devices, in addition of the media viewport of course.

Comment: This resolves  most of the main issues with the new reality. As what I was facing on my layout was that it would scew scroll in odd position far away from the view. This now forces the scroll x to be in frame always. Not blocking zoom in but atleast providing okay ux from it.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks for sharing @KyleMit

Comment: @JuliusDepulla, point of clarity - I just made an edit; /u/pollux1er was the one to post it originally.  Maybe /u/slyph can accept one after all these years; in the meantime, I'll bounty up a bit

Comment: Having position relative for `body` made display bugs for me, overflow on body and html worked fine tho

Comment: This is the best solution. There are times when you want to scroll on x so add those as needed. For example: h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {overflow-x:auto;}

Comment: This does not work if you require position sticky on child elements.

Comment: Not a very good answer. In desktop in now displays 2 scroll bars which is unaceptable.

Answer (score 58):

I've found this answer [over here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10595207/2298708) which works perfectly for me:

use this in style

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Use this in head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

A slight addition of mine in case your body has padding (to prevent the device from scaling to the body content-box, and thus still adding a horizontal scrollbar):

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: If your making an app and view it through a webview, its helpful to add this just to stop it scrolling left to right.         overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: I would add to test thoroughly. In some instances, using `overflow: hidden;` will lock your page at the top, with no ability to scroll down. As Mikeys4u relates, it's usually better to use `overflow-x: hidden;`.

Comment: I had to apply the CSS to the `html` element also for it to work, and I didn't need the `meta` tags.

Comment: This code still shows the horizontal scroll bar in my angualar app.

Answer (score 12):

For me, the viewport meta tag actually *caused* a horizontal scroll issue on the Blackberry.

I removed `content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;` from the viewport tag and it fixed the issue.  Below is my current viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0;"/>
```

Comment: Best answer because it works and let sticky-position works too !

Comment: Not a good idea if you want to keep your website accessible for everyone. Read: https://adrianroselli.com/2015/10/dont-disable-zoom.html

Answer (score 12):

Try this code,overflow will help to remove scrollbar.You can use it also for any div which is scrolling.

```
html, body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
 }
body {
   width:100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

This works for me across all mobile devices in both portrait and landscape modes.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 0.86, maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=0.86">`

Comment: Some of the other solutions here do not work for me. This works for me. However, I have to replace all the <p> elements with <div> elements to prevent the mobile browsers from prompting the "Show Simplified View" dialog.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but it's worth noting that BlackBerry doesn't support `overflow-x` or `overflow-y`.

See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850548/jquerymobile-phonegap-blackberry-webworks-enable-overflow-x-scroll-on-non/16957315#16957315)

Answer (score 3):

I use this to make the user still able to zoom in and out:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;" />
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this

**css**

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -msbox-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
img{
   max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Perfect Thats Solve My Problem

Answer (score 1):

In this case edit your meta viewport

Try this code below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that worked perfectly in my Angular app that didn't show 2 vertical srollbars in desktop mode and didn't show the horizontal scollbar in mobile mode which was a result of trying the two top voted answers.

```
html,
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply width:100%; to body

Answer (score 0):

Depending on box sizing width 100% might not always be the best option. I would suggest

```
 width:100vw;
 overflow-x: scroll;
```

This can be applied in the context of body, html as has been suggested or you could just wrap the content that is having an issue in a div with these settings applied.

Answer (score 0):

For my project leaving everthing as is and only adding this worked:`html{ overflow-x: hidden;}`
(Problem was in android 8 phones browsers)

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing an issue with just a bit of horizontal scroll in your page and have tested everything (tags and styles) and didn't find a solution, try to change `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`.

I don't know exactly why but using 1.0 prevents unintended horizontal overflow and scrolling on smaller screens.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Adding maximum-scale=1 fixed it:

OLD: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

NEW: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

P.S. Also I have been using commas between values. But it seems to work with semi-colon as well.