# How to lock the screen width for any browser?

Tags: javascript, android, css, screen, smartphone

Just go to this test website : ltdcoapp.uphero.com , from you smart phone and then slide the screen to see what is on the right and the problem is : that yes the screen slides and shows what I am trying to hide on the right side .

my attempts so far was to use `body{overflow-x: hidden;}` which only works with desktop browsers though .

can you please tell me what to do to prevent this ?

PS: I'm really not trying to get traffic to the website , but it is the only way to show you the problem easily

Comment: If you're trying to hide something, use `display:none;`

Comment: @ RobinvdA well the problem is that it has not be hidden , cuz its a slide show .

Comment: You could try to hide it, and only show it when it should slide in?

Comment: @RobinvdA no , can't do that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set a corresponding width with your overflow:hidden property?

**Edit:** Relative values like 100% for your width won't work (as they'll also contain the right part of the screen). Fix it to absolute pixel values (in this example: 1024px):

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden
    width: 1024px
}
```

It might also help to add the corresponding viewport meta-tags in the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=1024px, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Also, would disabling scrolling altogether be a solution? [Disable scrolling in all mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592411/disable-scrolling-in-all-mobile-devices)

Comment: could you try the new suggestions (i.e., viewport, fixing the width)?

Comment: tried that meta line with and without the {width: 1024px} line and nope , none of them worked.

is there is an option to prevent only horizontal scrolling ?

Answer (score 0):

This one will prevent any touch response , which is kinda useless in my situation .

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

This one will be very uselful , but the problem is that it prevents both horizontal and vertical scrolling.

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

This only works for desktop browsers .

```
body{overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Tried this a few times and all it do it to prevent user from scaling the page , which is useful at some point , but doesn't solve the problem of scrolling to the right .

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0;user-scalable=no" />
```

Thx dominikus , you surely helped .