# disable horizontal scroll for mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

i wish to disable the vertical scroll for mobile devices. using :

```
body {overflow-x:hidden}
```

works for normal browsers but on mobile if there's an element wider than the screen it will allow side scrolling.

i have tried using this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $body = $(document);
    $body.bind('scroll', function() {
        // "Disable" the horizontal scroll.
        if ($body.scrollLeft() !== 0) {
            $body.scrollLeft(0);
        }
    });
});
```

but it allows the side scrolling (on mobile) but "jumps" the scroll back to the right, this is not a perfect solution.

i have tried using this:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content=" width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" /> 
 $(document).bind("touchmove",function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
      });
```

this works perfect and disable the mobile scrolling totally, the problem is that it is disabling both horizontal and vertical scrolling (i wish to disable only the horizontal).

Comment: i don't see any jquery/js solutions on that post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592411/disable-scrolling-in-all-mobile-devices

Comment: Javascript solution for touch devices-- https://jsfiddle.net/6492jvb0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
  position: relative
}
```

Comment: in some cases this worked for me better: html, body {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

Comment: That's right. Surprisingly setting overflow to body only not working. Only html + body