# Prevent page scroll

Tags: html, css

I need to prevent page scroll, so I add the following style to body:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This works on desktop. On mobile it has no affect.

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270084/overflow-xhidden-doesnt-prevent-content-from-overflowing-in-mobile-browsers) a solution appears to be either adding a child div of body and adding a fixed position.

This works but causes the page to jump to the top if you fix the page when you are half way down the page.

How can I prevent scrolling on mobile without having the page jump to the top?

Comment: set `body { max-height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: Thanks Rohit Kumar but after testing, this does not work.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592411/disable-scrolling-in-all-mobile-devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML Solution:

```
// disable scrolling and scaling on mobile devices
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Javascript Solution:

```
document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

jQuery Solution:

```
$(document.body).on("touchmove", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```