# No matter what I do, overflow-x: hidden doesn't work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, overflow

I've been working on this website, and i cannot seems to disable the horizontal scrolling on mobile devices. I've looked up countless of questions concerning this problem, but none of them seem to solve my problem.

http://athostrainingcenter.be/home.html

So the overflow-x is disabled for desktop and even if I change the width of my browser on desktop it's also disabled. It's also disabled when I click on 'inspect' and view the website on a mobile device on my computer.

But when I open the website on my actual phone I can still scroll to the right. I wish there was just one solution that fits all.

Anyone who can give me any advice?

Cheers

Comment: I did not see any horizontal scroll

Comment: Please provide your platform and device - Safari is typically the culprit but there are ways around this problem - you just have to be more specific with information off the bat

Comment: Hmmm strange. When i open it on safari on my iphone I can scroll to the right and there a huge blank space there. a friend of mine could also scroll

Comment: devdev_dev I opened it on Safari indeed. On an iphone 11.

Comment: Duplicate of [Disable scrolling in all mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592411/disable-scrolling-in-all-mobile-devices)