# Jquerymobile + PhoneGap + Blackberry webworks + enable overflow-x scroll on non touch devices

Tags: jquery-mobile, blackberry, cordova

I Am developing a phoneGap application on Blackberry webworks. the overflow scroll property works fine on android, iphone..but it is not working on blackberry webworks on nonTouch devices.

Here is my code.

```
  <div class="ExternalClassTable" data-scroll="x" x-blackberry-focusable="true">
    <table>....</table>
  </div>

  css:
   .ExternalClassTable{
     width : 90%;
     max-width : 520px;
     overflow-x : scroll;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry doesn't support `overflow-x` or `overflow-y`, just `overflow`.

You may want to do something like this:

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```