# Bootstrap4: Width slightly too wide on mobile with animations (causes scroll at bottom)

Tags: css, animation, mobile, bootstrap-4, responsive

I'm making a website DEMO using Bootstrap Framework and AOS - Animate on scroll library.

In desktop I had to change some animations because they increased the width the page, with a horizontal scrolling.
For the mobile I have the same issues, but now I don't understand if the problem is caused from the animations or something else, I see the navbar larger.

Here is the link: https://doc.digitalsolutioner.com/

I've tried to fix wider elements like the navbar, but the issue remains.
I have seen in other issues similar about rows without containers, but it's not the case.

I want to have the right width on the mobile, with no horizontal scrolling.

[image: Screenshot with horizontal scrolling on mobile]

Comment: What you mean by _I see the navbar larger._ ? give image where you got problem, i don't see any problem in your website

Comment: Hi @NishargShah , thanks for comment. I added a screenshots about the horizontal scrolling on the mobile, don't you see that? The page is too wide. 

It could be the animations that increase the width, but I wouldn't want to deactivate them.

Comment: `fade-left` creates problem, so remove it or set initial state of your element

Comment: @NishargShah Yes you are right, I change the fade-left property and now it's ok. 
It's a shame because in the desktop it was fine as an animation. Thanks!

Comment: I added answer of it, check it out

Answer (score 1):

the **culprit** is the following class inside the footer... to check: go to the bottom of the page; do inspect element; remove this property (in browser developer tools) to see how it is causing the horizontal scroll to appear

```
[data-aos^=fade][data-aos^=fade].aos-animate
{   transform: translateZ(0);   }
```

simplest way to solve this will be to hide overflow-x property against your body. This css will be the **simplest way** to get the fade effect without seeing the scroll at the bottom:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**Update**:
on mobiles and mobile emulators, a horizontal bar appears... this was due to margins on the `card-service` class, just remove the margin-left and margin-right properties in the media-query (as shown below) to resolve this.

```
@media (max-width: 576px){
  .card-service {
     /* margin-left: 15px; */
     /* margin-right: 15px; */
     margin-bottom: 25px !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @AkberIqbal I see the property in the css, caused by the fade-left animation. If I put the overflow-x in the body the situation is the same in the mobile, I had to replace the fade-left animation. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: can you try adding this to your <head> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">` or check here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192277/disable-horizontal-scroll-on-mobile-web

Comment: hi @CarloVarchetta, I see what you meant... updated the answer based on your specific case; Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

In `AOS` there is problem, when you cant set initial position of your element, Its set to the default position.

Like in `fade-left` default position is `right: 0` so whenever you call `fade-left` its start from 0 and its create screen overflow.

So there is two option here,

1. Don't use `fade-left`
2. Set initial value of the element