# overflow-x not working on mobile phones 2021

Tags: html, css, mobile

So I read this question [disable horizontal scroll on mobile web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192277/disable-horizontal-scroll-on-mobile-web) the problem is that the answers are too old that they don't work nowadays, I try the solution they suggest that is

```
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

But it only works on desktop and still not on phone.

any ideas?

Comment: Did you try the other options, like setting `body { position: relative; }` or `body { width: 100% }`, or adding any of the `<meta>` tags suggested there?

Comment: @404NotFound yes but it doesn't work:(